# Accumulation point of zeros of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't know how to solve the following problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function. Suppose $0$ is accumulation point of the zeros of $f$, i.e. an accumulation point of $f^{-1}(0)$. Prove that either $f$ is identically zero, or $0$ is an essential singularity for $f$.

Comment: Complex analysis was a while ago, but I think this works.  Zero is either a pole (possibly of order zero) or an essential singularity.  If it is a pole then for sufficiently large $n$ $x^nf(x)$ is entire.  An entire function whose zeroes have an accumulation point is identically zero and therefore $f$ must be identically zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the other possibilities are a removable singularity or a pole.  A pole is easy to rule out.  For a removable singularity, $f(z)$ has a Maclaurin series ...

Comment: Yes, as you said a pole is easy to rule out. How about the removable singularity?

Comment: Consider the Maclaurin series; if $f$ is not identically zero, some coefficient in this series is nonzero.  $f(z)/z^n$, for the first $n$ where the coefficient is nonzero, extends to a continuous function in a neighbourhood of $0$ which is nonzero at $0$.  Do you see a contradiction arising from $0$ being an accumulation point of zeros of $f$?

Comment: Using the Maclaurin series is overkill. All you need is continuity of $f$: take a sequence in $f^{-1}(0)$ going to zero and then take the limit under $f$.

Comment: @JacobSchlather: So?  That just tells you $f(0)=0$.